# Dirichlet series for 1/ζ(s)

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, mobius-function

Prove that for Re(s)>1

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$

Where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function defined by:

$\mu(n)=1, \mbox{if }n=1$

$\mu(n)=(-1)^k, \mbox{if }n=p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ and $p_j$ are distinct primes

$\mu(n)=0, otherwise$

Hint: use the Euler product formula.

I started trying to use the Euler product formula for $\zeta(s)$ but no succes. How do I get this result?

Comment: What actually does the Euler product give for $1/\zeta(s)$?

Comment: I used the product formula for $\zeta(s)$, question edited

Comment: Is a comparison of the Euler product that you can need to calculate, and the Euler product corresponding to $\zeta(s)$. You need to see in you book how to calculate the corresponding Euler product (for the completely multiplicative function $\mu(n)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler Product$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_{p}(1-p^{-s})=(1-p_1^{-s})(1-p_2^{-s})(1-p_3^{-s})...$$

Due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, this product can be re-written as a sum over the integers. By foiling out the primes, each term in the sum can be seen to be made up of a product of different combinations of primes, and the sign of the term is based on the amount of prime factors it contains.

So $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$